# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/wicket/util/convert/converter/ZeroPaddingIntegerConverter

Tags: java, spring, wicket, wicket-8

My application was running fine with Wicket 7.6.0. But now I am facing below exception after migration from Wicket 7.6 to 8.5.

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/wicket/util/convert/converter/ZeroPaddingIntegerConverter
at org.apache.wicket.extensions.yui.calendar.DateTimeField.(DateTimeField.java:119)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: **org.apache.wicket.util.convert.converter.ZeroPaddingIntegerConverter**
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1358)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1180)
... 77 more

*In my code nowhere used this class "**ZeroPaddingIntegerConverter**" but still getting this error for this class.*

:
*ZeroPaddingIntegerConverter class has been deprecated in Wicket 8.x version.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wicket-datetime module has been removed with Wicket 8 and moved to [WicketStuff](https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/tree/master/wicket-datetime-parent). In your code you are probably mixing the old wicket-datetime module (7.6.0) with Wicket 8.5. Just remove the old module and replace it with WicketStuff dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.wicketstuff</groupId>
  <artifactId>wicket-datetime</artifactId>
  <version>8.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you Andrea, after adding this dependency it worked for me.

Comment: @user3552342 please vote up my answer if you found it helpful. Cheers!

Comment: Hi @Andrea Del Bene, please vote for my question, hope this can help others who face this same issue. Cheers!